# AppHost does not support accessing the current Request via a Singleton

Tags: servicestack

After upgrading to ServiceStack 4.0.38 when I call SessionFeature.GetSessionKey() I receive the error:

```
AppHost does not support accessing the current Request via a Singleton
```

Have you any idea how to solve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: What version were you upgrading from?

Comment: I'm upgrading from 4.0.23

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack allows optional `IRequest` parameters for some API's where it's able to infer the Request when the Host allows singleton access to the current Request. Currently this works in ASP.NET hosts which provides access to the current request via `HttpContext.Current`.

For HttpListener Self-Hosts you should always supply the Current `IRequest`, e.g:

```
var sessionKey = SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(base.Request);
```

Comment: OK, but with version 4.0.23 it worked. Its a change in latest versions?

Comment: @MatteoTomasini Doesn't look like it ever worked for self-hosts, [source code for v4.0.23 release](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v4.0.23/src/ServiceStack/SessionFeature.cs#L50-L74).

Comment: Actually, it looks like the behavior of `GetSessionId(IRequest req)` changed:  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v4.0.23/src/ServiceStack/SessionExtensions.cs#L21-L28  vs   https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/SessionExtensions.cs#L41-L49